# How to insert form controls value in QueryString in HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, query-string

I am facing a problem with inserting HTML form control's values in QueryString while redirecting to a next page.

I can give static values in a QueryString and I could retrieve those values using PHP's GET method, but having problem with values from HTML form Controls.

Please help me out from this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some codes what you've tried. That'll be useful to understand

Comment: Set the form's method to GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like that...

```
    var formValue = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    window.location="youform.php?formvalue="+formValue+;
```